# Segmentation fault when accessing a c string in a another function

Tags: c

I am writing a small program to get familiar with C again.
I have now a part of the program where I am stuck and can not go forward. I have a function where I create a c string and a pointer to the 2nd element of that string. (When it is finished it should receive a pointer to another string)
When I pass this strings to another function which should remove some elements on the first one I always get a segmentation fault. Which should mean, that I can't access that memory. But, if I change the order I pass the strings to the function I get the same error... .

Here is the code:

```
int analyze_sudoku(const void *self, Sudoku *sudoku) {
  for(int i = 1; i < 82; i++)
  {
    int success = 0;
    // All possible values of a column
    // This can be rewritten of course but this way
    // it makes the intention what this var is for
    // very clear in my opinion
    char options[10] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    char *chars_in_row;
    // The same problem...
    // chars_in_row = sudoku->get_row_for_column(sudoku, i);
    chars_in_row = &options[2];
    printf("In field %d we have this chars in the row: %s\n", i,chars_in_row);
    printf("length der chars: %d\n", strlen(chars_in_row));
    printf("addresse of the char pointers: %p\n", (void *)chars_in_row);
    // After receiving all chars from one row, we remove
    // those from the one we have in our options
    // HERE IS THE FUNCTION CALL
    remove_from_options(options, chars_in_row);
    // ... more code follows

  }
}
```

And here is the function where I get my seg fault:

```
char *remove_from_options(char *options, char *already_in_use) {
  puts("Welcome");
  printf("Your options: %s\n", options);
  // HERE THE SEG FAULT HAPPENS
  // as already mentioned the error happens no matter what I give this function
  printf("pointer address: %p", (void *)already_in_use);
  printf("already in use: %s", already_in_use);
  printf("in use länge: %d", strlen(already_in_use));
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(already_in_use); i++)
  {
    // some code...
  }
}
```

Comment: Questions *seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @melpomene I thought that the desired behaviour is very clear: To not get a seg fault but have access to the var in that function. Since I had absolutly no idea where the error happend I wrote more of the functions than maybe necessary. What would your suggestion for improvement be?

Comment: You didn't write more than necessary, you wrote not enough. This code is not complete; there isn't even a `main` function. If I wanted to compile it and try it myself, the first error would be that `Sudoku` is undeclared.

Comment: In other words, the part that's missing is *the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
char options[10] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

is not a string but array of characters. In C language, strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters **terminated by a null character '\0'**.

The `%s` format specifier, in `printf()`, writes every byte up to and not including the first null terminator. Since the `char` array `option` does not have the null character, the `printf()` must be accessing beyond the size of `option` array which is leading to segmentation fault.

Try adding the null character at the last of `option` array, like this:

```
char options[10] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','\0'};
```

---

**EDIT**

I totally missed the point that the last index of array `option` has been initialized with `0`. There is no need to explicitly give the null character at the end of `option` array. OP has accepted this as the answer because this, somehow, resolve the OP's problem. Hence, I can not delete this post. Minimal complete and verifiable example is required to identify the root cause of the problem mentioned by OP.

Comment: Those two initializers are equivalent. Your proposed change makes no difference.

Comment: It seems that they are not. After changing this, it worked! :-)

Comment: You're wrong, but I'd like to see your reasoning. Why do you think they're different?

Comment: It would be the same when I wrote it like this: "123456789".

Comment: @Shimu Yes, its same. When initialized with string literal the null terminated character is included.

Comment: @melpomene there is a difference between an array of characters and a string in C and the difference is null character.

Comment: @H.S. True, but irrelevant. What do you think is different about those initializers and why?

Comment: @melpomene if you are pointing towards the size `10` then the `10` size of `option` is big enough to include the `\0` character.

Comment: @H.S. That is exactly why those two initializers are equivalent. I'm not pointing towards anything; I'm trying to figure out what you think is different and you're not explaining your reasoning.

Comment: connect to melpomene, there is no diff between this two initializers... I think problem not related to this.

Comment: @JeffMercado There are no half-initialized variables in C. Every variable is either uninitialized or fully initialized. Since we have an explicit initializer, it is not uninitialized. If an initializer doesn't cover all elements of a variable, the remaining fields are zero-initialized. This is why `foo_t x = { 0 };` completely zero-initializes any variable.

Comment: @melpomene: Hmm, I'll defer to your judgement. If that's the case, then I'm mistaken. Haven't worked C in a while so details like this may be lost on me.

Comment: @melpomene I agree with you, i totally missed this point. I am deleting my answer. MVC is required to identify the root cause of problem.

Comment: @melpomene I cannot delete this answer since it has been accepted.

Comment: That is strange since this change solved my problem. Maybe this has something to do with the compiler? (gcc)

Comment: @Shimu, remove your acceptance as answer to this post. I should delete it.

Comment: @Shimu That's the beauty of Undefined Behavior. Your code still has some problem even though this might've "solved" it. It might break when you've made another small modification elsewhere etc. This answer is incorrect as suggested by melpomene and the answerer itself. Please unaccept it so that the answerer can delete it